# Recently updated from 20.04.1 LTS to 20.04.3 LTS and have an issue with version number

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

After updating to 20.04.3 LTS I tried installing Authy, no errors but when I run it nothing happens.
My question is that in troubleshooting this I found that running `uname -a` I get:

```
Linux carson-Aspire-A515-43 5.11.0-41-generic #45~***20.04.1***-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However running `hostnamectl` I see:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this discrepancy?

Comment: What is `updating to 20.04.3 LTS`? From what did you update? How did you do that?

Comment: What does ` lsb_release -a` report? Probably the update will be OK, though, as your kernel version corresponds with the .3 version.

Answer (score 3):

The command `uname -a` only gives you the kernel version. It seems your current kernel is designated with a version string that includes 20.04.1.

However, this has nothing to do with your current release. As such, `hostnametcl` and `lsb_release -a` should report 20.04.3, which is your release version.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question